# Expresión regular para nombre propio en español

Tags: c#, regex

**Quisiera saber como puedo incluir los caracteres áéíóú y ñ a la siguiente expresión regular.**

```
@"^(?=.{1,40}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$"
```

Intenté ponerlo de la siguiente forma pero al finalizar una palabra con una vocal con "acento" o "ñ" no hace match, debe estar en medio de algún otro carácter para que funcione.

```
@"^(?=.{1,40}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[áéíóúñ\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$"
```

*Ejemplo: Si introduzco "José", no hace match, por otro lado con "Jóse" funciona perfectamente.*

**Es mi primer pregunta al foro, por lo que no se si el formato de mi pregunta es la correcta, me disculpo. Y de antemano muchas gracias.**

Comment: Quedó muy bien redactada tu pregunta, expones la duda, lo que has intentado así como casos en los que funciona y casos en los que no 

Comment: Muchas gracias, espero poder aportar algo bueno a esta comunidad. Un saludo

Comment: Pero la respuesta si quedo corta, checa [answer] si editas y explicas y das contexto entonces si utilidad se amplia

Answer (score 1):

**Si alguien lo necesita, de la siguiente forma me funcionó perfectamente:**

```
^(?=.{1,40}$)[a-zA-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÑ]+(?:[\s][a-zA-ZáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÑ]+)*$
```

Saludos.